# Consolidate sed command

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sed, ksh

I have a string called $string

```
string='-d $DESTDIR/ERRORS/$BASEDIR ]] || $MKDIR -p     word1 word22   word3.5'
```

Currently I am piping this through sed twice. Once to pull out special characters and then again to change spaces/tabs to single space.

```
echo $string | sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/ /g' | sed 's/\s\s*/ /g'
output='d DESTDIR ERRORS BASEDIR MKDIR p word1 word22 word3 5'
```

Although this works I am looking to gain some efficiency. 
Can someone help me consolidate this to a single sed command?

EDIT
I should have noted that this needs to be POSIX compatible for HP/SOL/LIN

Answer (score 2):

Use `tr`:

```
echo $string | tr -Cs a-zA-Z0-9 ' '
```

`tr` is a very powerful (and fast) tool for translating, deleting and squeezing characters.

This particular command translates every character from the `C`omplement of the first set (`a-zA-Z0-9`) into characters from the second set; since the second set contains only a space, this translates all non-alphanumeric characters (including tabs) into spaces. It then `s`queezes all sequences of characters from the second character set into a single character; this replaces runs of spaces with single spaces.

Example:

```
$ string='-d $DESTDIR/ERRORS/$BASEDIR ]] || $MKDIR -p     word1 word22   word3.5'
$ output=$(echo $string | tr -Cs 'a-zA-Z0-9' ' ')
$ echo $output
d DESTDIR ERRORS BASEDIR MKDIR p word1 word22 word3 5
```

Comment: never used tr...is that posix compatible?

Comment: Yes, from `man tr`: *The tr utility conforms to IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 (``POSIX.1'').*

Comment: After some more testing it does not like "C" on my HP or Solaris boxes. I tried "c" but that does not produce the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo $string | sed -r 's/[^[:alnum:]]/ /g;s/ +/ /g'
```

Guru.

Comment: `[[:alnum:]]` is locale sensitive.

Comment: My `sed` doesn't have `-r`...can you write it without using that?

Comment: The -r is requires to consolidate the spaces...I too do not have that on HP or SOL